# pip library is not visible with sudo

Tags: python, pip, sudo

I am trying to inatall one of libraries for python (plotly). I used command:

```
pip install -U plotly
```

to get permission denied error... okay.
so i put:

```
sudo pip install -U plotly
```

to get:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement plotly (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for plotly

something is wrong with this debian setup, but I cannot figure out what. To check, I've used same commands for paramiko... all went ok.

Comment: Which Python are you using? The output of `sudo python -V` should tell you. The best practices for installing pip packages is in a virtualenv so I'd recommend creating one to isolate your project dependencies from system libraries. BTW, plotly package info is at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plotly

Comment: Have you tried to put the full pip path?

Comment: A permission denial when running `pip install -U` is already a bad sign and indicates a broken python installation in user homedir. Seems like you have messed up running user-related commands with `sudo`. Try fixing by `sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) ~/.local`, then rerun `pip install --user plotly` to see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone created /root/.pip/pip.conf with extra settings :/

Answer (score 0):

try using "sudo pip install plotly" tested on ubuntu 17.1 using python 2.7

Comment: No difference. I know, that library is in pip. Checked it on another pc too. The issue is pip setup/config related.

Comment: which python version you are using? if you are using python 3 then u need to install pip3 to install python packages. install pip by using following command sudo apt-get install python3-pip and then try to install required packages.

Comment: also 2.7
by verbose i've foud that:

lteadm@SFE-ROBOT-PC-1:~$ sudo pip -v install plotly
Collecting plotly
  1 location(s) to search for versions of plotly:
  * http://pypi.<SOME_IMPROPER_ADDRESS>.com:25102/plotly/

Answer (score 0):

Since you feel that the issue is in pip setup/config, try easy_install.

`easy_install plotly`